Raspberry Pi 5 to LG UltraFine 4K Monitor via USB-C: No Display
I'm trying to connect my Raspberry Pi 5 to an LG UltraFine 4K monitor using a micro-HDMI to HDMI adapter and an HDMI to USB-C adapter on the monitor. The monitor has only USB-C ports, and the Pi's USB-C port is used for power.
Despite this setup, the monitor shows no output. I've searched for solutions but found none.
Can the issue be resolved by modifying the config.txt file? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

You need an adapter which takes HDMI and outputs it to USB-C. I have searched for one of these in the past, but could only find adapters that work in the other direction, where the input is at the USB-C end and the output is an HDMI plug. Unfortunately these things are not bidirectional. If anyoune finds one, please post a link.

Which operating system are you using? Googling that instead of Raspberry Pi may get your further in your search. Also, you did not say who the monitor's OEM was. They may have published a LInux driver for their monitor. Is this a DisplayLink interface? Maybe this web site will help.

Modifying the config.txt file can sometimes resolve display issues on Raspberry Pi, it's more commonly used for configuring display settings like resolution and refresh rate.

Welcome. Have you tried using this cable to plug any other device into the monitor?1 Pretty sure Lee-xp 's point is correct (also sure  we've seen exactly this issue here before).  If you search online for "HDMI to USB-C" you'll get hits, but if you click through to an actual product description/ad, these are all sold as USB-C to HDMI.
https://www.hdmi.org/spec/typec#:~:text=The%20HDMI%C2%AE%20Alt%20Mode,and%20connector%20adapters%20or%20dongles clarifies this:
The language may be a bit confusing:

The HDMI® Alt Mode for USB Type-CTM connector allows HDMI-enabled source devices to utilize a USB Type-C® connector...

What this does not mean is that HDMI source devices can plug an adapter into their HDMI jack and output at the other end to USB-C.  The HDMI protocol is not just about the shape of the connecter; what it means is that (like most contemporary smart phones) a device with no HDMI jack can implement the HDMI protocol in hardware and output that stream via a USB-C jack.  You can then use a USB-C to HDMI connector to output to a normal HDMI screen/projector.  This is clear from the rest of the context on that page

...to directly connect to HDMI-enabled displays, and deliver HDMI signals and features over a simple cable without the need for protocol and connector adapters or dongles.



Presuming I'm right and this is not what the cable was intended for, and that the monitor is intended to potentially provide power to a phone or laptop at the same time as it streams a signal from them, there is maybe a potential for trouble here, but I think the USB-C protocol has enough controls and dynamism in it that it should not accidentally damage that device -- but it is up to you to decide if you want to do that and I won't unreservedly recommend it.

